# IE 8 doesn't support nth-child how can I solve this?

Tags: css

IE 8 doesn't support nth-child how can I solve this problem ?

```
 #hm-top div:nth-child(1) h3 {
    color: #63c2ff;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 115px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/trade.png) no-repeat center top;
    }
```

Comment: [Poor man’s nth-child selector for IE 7 and 8](http://abouthalf.com/development/poor-mans-nth-child-selector-for-ie-7-and-8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
equivalent to li:nth-child(1)
li:first-child { /* change to this */
    border-top: 5px solid red;
}
equivalent to li:nth-child(2)
li:first-child + li { /* change to this */
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
}
equivalent to li:nth-child(3)
 li:first-child + li + li { /* change to this */
    border-top: 5px solid green;
}​
```

Answer (score 5):

IE8 however supports [:first-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child) which is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`:

```
#hm-top div:first-child h3 {
    color: #63c2ff;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 115px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/trade.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it with jQuery. Like this:

```
$('#hm-top div:nth-child(1) h3').addClass('ie8-nth-fix');
```

And in you CSS

```
#hm-top div:nth-child(1) h3, .ie8-nth-fix {
   color: #63c2ff;
   width: 300px;
   padding: 115px 0 0 0;
   background: url(images/trade.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: Did you see any javascript/jquery tag in OP's question ?